# list view issue in android

Tags: android

I am using a custom list view. I have tried to get the value of the row which the user clicked. 
Can anybody tell me how to get the value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to implement a new method in your class, specifically `onItemClick`:

```
[...]
private ListView lv;
[...]
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    String itemValue = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
    [... do something ...]
}
```

Then you can do whatever you want with with `itemValue`.
Hope this helps.